# Why did they keep the styling properties on web server controls?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

Why did .NET Framework 4 keep these properties on web server controls?

- BorderStyle
- BorderWidth
- BorderColor
- ForeColor
- BackColor
- Font
- Height
- Width

Is there ever a good reason to set these properties, and keep the styling within the code, rather than move it to a CSS file? I can't think of any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there ever a good reason to set these properties, and keep the styling within the code, rather than move it to a CSS file? I can't think of any.

Suppose you have a control where the text should be in red for one user, but green for another. The user colour preference is stored in a database (so that it can be persisted and maintained without requiring a redeploy).

One approach would be to pull that data at execution time, dynamically create css, and somehow make sure the browser didn't cache it. This might work, and would certainly be *interesting*!

Or you could just set these properties from code-behind.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good scenario where these properties would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well those properties have been there since a while and would you imagine how many ASP.NET controls, sites, component libraries and other things would break if they removed?

We could argue or not that should not have been there in the first place but the assumption was to help the developers with limited CSS know how to start working and having a web page easy to style and build/publish.

I am thankful they did not remove those properties and did not break all existing previously written code.

Comment: Alright, that's a fair point. Would removing them from intellisense help? Obviously this has got nothing to do with .NET 4 Framework but it would keep new code clean but still work for previously written code.

Comment: no because then people will complain intellisense does not work. It's a no point this one anyway, people are free to use css or those properties and no restrictions are made.

Comment: Last one now. How about showing a warning like intellisense does on the `name` attribute on some controls?